# Adding multiple transform values to one element in CSS

Tags: html, css, parallax, css-transforms

I have an element on which I have parallax effect applied by using transform translate3d depending on the page scroll

Some of the elements with the parallax effects have shadows applied, on which I also add translateY() element on hover for elevation effect.

```
@mixin shadow-1 {
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    &:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
        *         -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
        *         transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
}
```

Obviously, it isn't working, because You can just have 1 transform on each element at once.

Is there any way to add +X px the existing transform value?

I cannot connect those 2 since not all parallax elements will have shadow on it, and not all of the elements with shadow will have parallax effect.

Right now only the elements without parallax works as suppose (only one transform at a time)

Comment: add it to a parent element